# knockoutjs how to get the selected option arrayObject

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want to get the selected option  object

```
    <select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                       value: selectedCountry, event: { select: onSelect}"></select>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // Constructor for an object with two properties
    var Country = function(name, population) {
        this.countryName = name;
        this.countryPopulation = population;   
    };       

    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray([
            new Country("UK", 65000000),
            new Country("USA", 320000000),
            new Country("Sweden", 29000000)
        ]),
        selectedCountry : ko.observable(), // Nothing selected by default
        onSelect: function(){
              console.log(viewModel.selectedCountry)
              // it is showing just an country name and what i what is whole object
              // e.g. { "UK", 65000000 } // that is selected option in selected box

        }

    };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post a your real code maybe in a JSFiddle? Because what you have shown should work see: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7A76/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9MKce/3/

Comment: Just remove the `optionsValue:'name'` and it will work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/9MKce/4/

Comment: thanks @nemesv but it will creating problem while data-bind 
<span data-bind="text: selectedSlider "></span>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have to add select event to the control. More efficient way is to subscribe on `selectedCountry` changes:

```
viewModel.selectedCountry.subscribe(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

If you don't want any country is selected by default you have to add `optionsCaption` binding to the `data-bind`:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                       optionsText: 'countryName',
                       value: selectedCountry,
                       optionsCaption: 'Select...'"></select>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/tuMta/1/

Comment: console.log(data) // dump only string of selected value
and i want associate data array

Comment: It doesn't return just a string, it returns selected element of array(i.e. Object { countryName= "UK", countryPopulation=65000000}).

Comment: You get just a string in selecetedCountery because of optionsValue:'name'. Remove it from the binding.